# How to fix the error "Expression is not a function locator" in C?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I was programming in C to write a simple program to learn about matrices and for loops, and when I compiled it, I got this error:
`(39,23) : ERROR (138) Expression is not a function locator`
`(44,23) : ERROR (138) Expression is not a function locator`

Note: This was C code made using the C toolkit for the TI-84 Plus Ce ([Link to source code](https://github.com/CE-Programming/toolchain/))

I tried manually putting in indices for the matrix `canvas[0][0]` and changing what is being assigned to the matrix index, and still got the error

Here is the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <tice.h>
#include <graphx.h>

static float cube[8][3] = 
{
    {-1.0,-1.0,-1.0},
    {1.0,-1.0,1.0},
    {1.0,-1.0,2.0},
    {-1.0,-1.0,2.0},
    {-1.0,1.0,1.0},
    {1.0,1.0,1.0},
    {1.0,1.0,2.0},
    {-1.0,1.0,2.0}
};

float canvas[8][2] = 
{
    {0.0,0.0},
    {0.0,0.0},
    {0.0,0.0},
    {0.0,0.0},
    {0.0,0.0},
    {0.0,0.0},
    {0.0,0.0},
    {0.0,0.0}
};

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t c;
    uint8_t r;
    for (c = 0; c < 7; c++)
    {
        for (r = 0; r < 1; r++)
        {
            if (r == 0)
            {
                canvas[c][0] = 20(cube[c][0] * cube[c][2]);
                canvas[c][r] = 160 + canvas[c][r];
            }
            else
            {
                canvas[c][1] = 20(cube[c][1] * cube[c][2]);
                canvas[c][r] = 120 + (-canvas[c][r]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of that error before, but `20(cube[c][0] * cube[c][2])` needs to be `20 * (cube[c][0] * cube[c][2])` if you intend multiplication there. I guess it might be saying that it knows that `20` isn't a function?

Comment: What do you expect `20(cube[c][0] * cube[c][2]);` to do?

Comment: What do you think the `20` is doing here `20(cube[c][0] * cube[c][2])`? If you meant 20 *times* then you need to add `*`. C doesn't let you use abbreviations like mathematics does.

Comment: Thanks, Carcigenicate, that fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 lines contain errors:

```
canvas[c][0] = 20(cube[c][0] * cube[c][2]);
canvas[c][1] = 20(cube[c][1] * cube[c][2]);
```

Your compiler reads `20(...` as a function, hence the error message, if you mean to multiply by 20 simply add `20 * (...`